# Does useCallback improve performance when rendering components inside a normal function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I have a component which I in this case I am reusing in a custom hook, like so...

```
const ListItem = ({name, ...rest}) => <div {...rest}>{name}</div>

const useList = props => {
  const data = [
    //...some array of objects
  ]
  
  function renderListItems() {
    return data.map(({ name, ...rest }) => (
      <ListItem name={name} {...rest} />
      ))
  }
}
```

Is there any benefit to wrapping renderListItems() in useCallback(), like this?

```
const useList = props => {
  const data = [
    //...some array of objects
  ]
  

  const renderListItems = useCallback(() =>{
    return data.map(({ name, ...rest }) => (
      <ListItem name={ name } { ...rest } />
    ))
  },[data])
  
  return {
    renderListItems
  }
}
```

Comment: No because `data` is a new reference every time `useList()` is called. Move the definition of `data` outside the body of `useList` and then it will be more efficient to call `useCallback()` here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In reality my "data" comes from a call to useContext as it comes from an API, so moving it outside of the hooks isn't possible. What I have considered though, is wrapping the child components in React.memo, but I don't know if that will do anything either given that they are rendered in this function. Do you happen to know?

Comment: if your `data` is comming from `props` then it will only be updated when `data` changes.
so maybe try to pass it via props instead of using it as `const`

Comment: My reason for not doing that is I was under the impression that if data is an object such as an array, it will always fail an equality check and React will always think it has changed even if it hasn't actually changed? Am I under the wrong impression, or is there some workaround for that?

Comment: so make sure your `data` is only changing when new data comes in.
basically, you're in the control of the change. if you don't re-assign it without a reason, then reference stays the same, and it won't re-render